# Print if there is a number combination that equals the given number

Tags: c, list, algorithm

I had this question in my exam a few weeks ago (Failed to answer it) and I wanted to know how to solve this kind of questions because I see they repeat themselves.

Write C program that gets Integers till -1 is inserted. if certain product of previously written numbers is equal to the last entered integer - the program will print it.

I know its pretty hard to understand but here are few examples :
(Typed order left to right)
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 (Will print 2 * 3=6) -> 36 (Will print 2 * 3 * 6) -> -1

I can see that the problem is hard to do with arrays because of the memory limitation...
so I though of using "List" but ain't got idea how to.

I don't want a complete solution! I would like to get any hint on how to solve it in C (C# is also ok but C preferred).

Comment: If after entering `36` I then enter `18`, does the program print `3 * 6 = 18`, or does it print nothing?

Comment: yes it prints 3 * 6 , It will print 1 combination each time if there is one , if not it will print nothing. it will keep doing so untill -1 is entered (of course the assumption is that the entered numbers are positive)

Comment: A `List<T>` is just a fancy wrapper around an array, so whatever "memory limitation" you're referring to wouldn't be solved by using a list.

Comment: how would you do it "manually"? can you apply that in code? even a brute-force version? start there.

Comment: hint: you can use the modulus operator to determine if one number is evenly divisible by another by comparing the result to `0`. For example, `6 % 2 == 0` and `36 % 3 == 0`

Comment: I though about using modulus but the amount of number that are included in the modulus are changing. for example when the you type 36 , 36%6==0 and 36%3==0 and 36%2==0 , you still need to check if its a multiplification of the 3 numbers and then 2 numbers and so on..

Comment: Roach87, Should not `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6` also print `1 * 2 * 3=6`?

Comment: Memory is not what makes this problem hard to solve: a simple recursive implementation will easily find the matching combinations, the problem is time complexity: the number of combinations to test grows exponentially. Finding an efficient solution is **hard** although some simple pruning techniques will keep the time within reasonable limits.

Answer (score 0):

Use a do-while cycle with condition and a counting sort.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a raw program that does what you want with the exception that it always considers `1` as the product of previous numbers, and the same is true for numbers that were already entered. I leave you the challenge to fix the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

void combo( int pro, int sum );

int n[SIZE], found, i;

int main() {

    for( ; i < SIZE && scanf("%d", &n[i]) == 1 && n[i] != -1; i++) {
        
        found = 0;
        
        combo(1,0);
        
        if( found ) printf("%d ", n[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void combo( int pro, int sum )
{
    if( pro == n[i] ) found = 1;
    
    for(int j = 0; j < i - sum && !found; j++) {
        
        combo(pro * n[j], sum + 1);
    }
}
```

`n, found, i` don't have to be global variables, but since `combo` could call itself lots of times, I thought it would have been a good idea to avoid giving it many arguments. I really don't know if it actually is a good idea.

Anyway, the program is a brute force. `combo()` will try every possible products of the elements of `n`.

For each `j`, `combo` will call itself generating a new loop, and for each index of this new loop there will be another recursive call generating a whole new loop, and so on.

`combo` stops to call itself when all the loops stop  running.
A loop stops when either a matching product has been found or `j` reaches `i - sum`, where `i` is the current number of elements stored in the array minus 1, while `sum` represents the number of elements involved in the current product.

Every time, before to enter a loop, the function checks whether the current product matches the last number entered in the array.

If you know that the numbers are entered in ascending order you can optimize by swapping `!found` with `pro < n[i]`.
I haven't done the math, but in case the input consists in a sequence of random integers, it may be more efficient to sort the array before to call `combo` in `main`.